# Count foreach and display in menu php

Tags: php, functions

how to count the elements inside a foreach and display the amount in wp-menu. I have the following code to count the elements but can't get a solution to echo it in the menu

```
        <?php
            $count = 0; //Hier ist der Count-Begin-Foreach
            foreach ( $bookmarks as $bookmark ) :                                       

            $count++; //Hier ist der Count-Inner-Foreach

            if ( get_post_status( $bookmark->post_id ) !== 'publish' ) {
                continue;
            }
            $has_bookmark = true;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td width="50%">

                    <?php echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $bookmark->post_id ) . '">' . get_the_title( $bookmark->post_id ) . '</a>'; ?>
                    <ul class="job-manager-bookmark-actions">
                        <?php
                            $actions = apply_filters( 'job_manager_bookmark_actions', array(
                                'delete' => array(
                                    'label' => __( 'Delete', 'wp-job-manager-bookmarks' ),
                                    'url'   =>  wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( 'remove_bookmark', $bookmark->post_id ), 'remove_bookmark' )
                                )
                            ), $bookmark );
                            foreach ( $actions as $action => $value ) {
                                echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $value['url'] ) . '" class="job-manager-bookmark-action-' . $action . '">' . $value['label'] . '</a></li>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td width="50%">
                    <?php echo wpautop( wp_kses_post( $bookmark->bookmark_note ) ); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php print "Sie haben " . $count . " Lesezeichen gesetzt."; //Hier ist der Count-Output?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing `$count` but I see you're referencing `$counter`. Not sure if those are different but here is a version that uses the same variable in all those places.

```
$counter = 0; //Hier ist der Count-Begin-Foreach
foreach ( $bookmarks as $bookmark ) :

    if ( get_post_status( $bookmark->post_id ) !== 'publish' ) {
        continue;
    }

    // moving below the if statement

    $counter ++; //Hier ist der Count-Inner-Foreach

    $has_bookmark = true;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">
            <?php echo $counter ?>

            <?php echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $bookmark->post_id ) . '">' . get_the_title( $bookmark->post_id ) . '</a>'; ?>
            <ul class="job-manager-bookmark-actions">
                <?php
                $actions = apply_filters( 'job_manager_bookmark_actions', array (
                        'delete' => array (
                                'label' => __( 'Delete', 'wp-job-manager-bookmarks' ),
                                'url'   => wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( 'remove_bookmark', $bookmark->post_id ), 'remove_bookmark' ),
                        ),
                ), $bookmark );
                foreach ( $actions as $action => $value ) {
                    echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $value[ 'url' ] ) . '" class="job-manager-bookmark-action-' . $action . '">' . $value[ 'label' ] . '</a></li>';
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td width="50%">
            <?php echo wpautop( wp_kses_post( $bookmark->bookmark_note ) ); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php print "Sie haben " . $counter . " Lesezeichen gesetzt."; //Hier ist der Count-Output?>
```

---

If you want to get the count, you might as well make a function to do just that. Then call it directly. I have no idea where `$bookmarks` is coming from so you'll have to figure that one out.

```
function get_number_of_bookmarks( $bookmarks = array () ) {
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ( $bookmarks as $bookmark ) :
        if ( get_post_status( $bookmark->post_id ) !== 'publish' ) {
            continue;
        }
        $counter ++;
    endforeach;
    return $counter;
}
?>

<div class="primary nav-menu">
<?php 
    // do your menu
    echo primary_nav_menu();

    // Example with an empty array, but this should be your bookmarks array
    $bookmarks_array = array();

    // echo the count
    echo get_number_of_bookmarks( $bookmarks_array );
?>
</div>
```

Comment: hi jgraup, the <? php echo $counter ?> in line 14 was wrong and i removed it. do you have an idea how to call the php and echo the counter in the menu? brg, nikita

Comment: I'm not really sure what I'm looking at here. Is this code to make a menu? Looks like a table with an unordered list. Can you make a sample of what the HTML output should be and where you expect the counter?

Comment: You are right. This code generates a table and count the elements inside of it. I would like to grab the counted amount and view it on the menu...

Comment: Cool, but without you showing that menu it's impossible to help you. The word menu can take thousands of different meanings in code. You will need to show all your code for further assistance.

Comment: Ouh.. i see. With "menu" i don't mean a specific code or class. Just the usual primary navigation menu at the top of each site.

Comment: Again, you need to supply the code your using and your expected output. It's not clear what your trying to do.

Comment: With this code I'm trying to output it [link](https://codepad.co/snippet/dnpH5P74)

Comment: So, you want to load another file just to get the count of the bookmarks. I think there is a better way.

Comment: Added an option. That's the extent of effort I can give for 10 points.

Comment: i added the function into my function.php and edited the headers <div>. but what do i have to do with the "$bookmarks_array = array();" ? :/ the actual output is "0"

Comment: @NikitaPankratz you need to give it your actual array of bookmarks you want it to count. I'm just using an empty array here for demo purposes.